# DateTime perhaps overwritten while during nested for loop

Tags: php, for-loop

I hope someone can help with this, i think perhaps the issue is i am overwriting the DateTime value in my second for loop, because its not outputting correct values, but not entirely sure.

```
<?php

$begin_from = new DateTime( "2023-01-01" );
$end_from   = new DateTime( "2023-12-31" );

$begin_to = new DateTime( "2023-01-31" );
$end_to   = new DateTime( "2023-12-31" );

for($i = $begin_from; $i <= $end_from; $i->modify('+1 month')){
    for($k = $begin_to; $k <= $end_to; $k->modify('first day of')->modify('+1 month')->modify('last day of')){
    echo $i->format("Y-m-d"),'..',$k->format("Y-m-d");
    echo "\n";
    }
}
```

From the code above its outputting this:

```
2023-01-01..2023-01-31
2023-01-01..2023-02-28
2023-01-01..2023-03-31
2023-01-01..2023-04-30
2023-01-01..2023-05-31
2023-01-01..2023-06-30
2023-01-01..2023-07-31
2023-01-01..2023-08-31
2023-01-01..2023-09-30
2023-01-01..2023-10-31
2023-01-01..2023-11-30
2023-01-01..2023-12-31
```

But, if you run these for loops separately you will get the correct values like below.

```
2023-01-01..2023-01-31
2023-02-01..2023-02-28
2023-03-01..2023-03-31
2023-04-01..2023-04-30
2023-05-01..2023-05-31
2023-06-01..2023-06-30
2023-07-01..2023-07-31
2023-08-01..2023-08-31
2023-09-01..2023-09-30
2023-10-01..2023-10-31
2023-11-01..2023-11-30
2023-12-01..2023-12-31
```

Can anyone tell what i am doing wrong here?

Comment: Do you always want the full calendar of months? https://3v4l.org/OrVRR

Comment: You're looping all the way through the inner loop before `$i->modify` gets called again. Try defining `$begin_to` and `$end_to` within the **first** loop. Since the next time the first loop gets called, `$k` (which is referencing `$begin_to`) has been changed.

Comment: Even with that, I don't think you need 2 loops if you're just trying to get every month between a date range (inclusive). That can be done in a single loop as some of the answers have already shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mutable objects are really hard to reason about. In particular, you need to be aware that `$bar = $foo` makes `$bar` point at the same object as `$foo`, *not* at a new object with the same value.

With that in mind, let's "unroll" your loops ([never write code like this!](https://xkcd.com/292/)):

```php
$begin_from = new DateTime( "2023-01-01" );
$end_from   = new DateTime( "2023-12-31" );

$begin_to = new DateTime( "2023-01-31" );
$end_to   = new DateTime( "2023-12-31" );

$i = $begin_from;
outerforloop:
if ( $i <= $end_from ) {

    $k = $begin_to;
    innerforloop:
    if ( $k <= $end_to ) {
        echo $i->format("Y-m-d"),'..',$k->format("Y-m-d");
        echo "\n";
    
        $k->modify('first day of')->modify('+1 month')->modify('last day of');
        goto innerforloop;
    }

    $i->modify('+1 month');
    goto outerforloop;
}
```

In particular, look at the start and end of the inner loop:

- `$k = $begin_to;` will make `$k` point at the same object as `$begin_to`
- `$k->modify(...)` will then modify that object, meaning both `$k` *and* `$begin_to` have moved forward by a month
- Next time around the loop, we check `$k <= $end_to`, with the expected result
- However, when we come back around the *outer* loop, we run `$k = $begin_to;` again, expecting this to *reset the value*; but `$k` and `$begin_to` already point at the same object, which has been modified; the assignment doesn't do anything
- So now when we check `$k <= $end_to`, it will already be false: we won't go into the loop at all

To actually copy the *value* of object, you can use the [`clone` keyword](https://www.php.net/clone), e.g. `$k = clone $begin_to;`

However, this particular case is why [the `DateTimeImmutable` class](https://www.php.net/DateTimeImmutable) was created. With `DateTimeImmutable`, you never change the value of an existing object, and instead always assign the result somewhere. In short, replace `$i->modify(...)` with `$i = $i->modify(...)` and `$k->modify(...)` with `$k = $k->modify(...)`:

```php
$begin_from = new DateTimeImmutable( "2023-01-01" );
$end_from   = new DateTimeImmutable( "2023-12-31" );

$begin_to = new DateTimeImmutable( "2023-01-31" );
$end_to   = new DateTimeImmutable( "2023-12-31" );

for($i = $begin_from; $i <= $end_from; $i = $i->modify('+1 month')){
    for($k = $begin_to; $k <= $end_to; $k = $k->modify('first day of')->modify('+1 month')->modify('last day of')){
    echo $i->format("Y-m-d"),'..',$k->format("Y-m-d");
    echo "\n";
    }
}
```

That fixes your for loops ... but it doesn't give the results you wanted. That's because if you have two nested loops with 12 iterations each, the result is going to be 144 iterations - think of filling out a grid with 12 columns and 12 rows.

What you actually wanted was a *single* loop, which controls both the start and the end date. There are a few ways to write that, but the most similar to your existing code is probably to keep the loop for `$i`, then define `$k` based on it:

```php
$begin_from = new DateTimeImmutable( "2023-01-01" );
$end_from   = new DateTimeImmutable( "2023-12-31" );

for($i = $begin_from; $i <= $end_from; $i = $i->modify('+1 month')){
    $k = $i->modify('last day of');
    echo $i->format("Y-m-d"),'..',$k->format("Y-m-d");
    echo "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why your code produces that output, but it can be simplified using a `while` loop. You just need one date to manually modify within each loop, and one target date (`DateTimeImmutable` is recommended for datetimes that are meant to remain unchanged)

```php
$i_date = new DateTime( "2023-01-01" );
$end_date = new DateTimeImmutable( "2023-12-31" );


while($i_date <= $end_date){
    // echo first of month..
    echo $i_date->format("Y-m-d..");
    // goto last of month
    $i_date->modify('last day of');
    // echo last of month \n
    echo $i_date->format("Y-m-d") . "\n";

    // goto first of next month for the next iteration
    $i_date->modify('first day of')->modify('+1 month');
}
```

The above will produce the following in PHP v7+:

```
2023-01-01..2023-01-31
2023-02-01..2023-02-28
2023-03-01..2023-03-31
2023-04-01..2023-04-30
2023-05-01..2023-05-31
2023-06-01..2023-06-30
2023-07-01..2023-07-31
2023-08-01..2023-08-31
2023-09-01..2023-09-30
2023-10-01..2023-10-31
2023-11-01..2023-11-30
2023-12-01..2023-12-31
```

PHP v5.6.40 requires you set the timezone or the default timezone like `date_default_timezone_set('UTC');` before creating the `DateTime`s, but then you get the same output as above.

[Run it live here.](https://onlinephp.io?s=fY3BCsIwDIbvg71DKINtSIebRzc96MW7HgShVNuywtqOWRkqvrut6BRBSQ4h-fL95byt2zBg1HLCuKCnxhIrFb8YzcmR2yTerBdxOg2DMIgk8RxUoHkPSzeuHZkAKsbFBI9z1wg8GnHNiOiMAviCV0qdLN03w1de4Mnzy1dfS3d7BZUVDKr0GgZOB_xQG3gCeCZMp6hN0BYrzLIMeY-nBkAZJsU5iRt6tMDoGYyIX9AfFUohA7TT6JdPyO5D-N6PclBG2_oRcrsD&v=8.2.1%2C8.0.27%2C7.4.33%2C7.0.33%2C5.6.40)

Comment: Perhaps concerningly, your script does not respect the input's end date on the final iteration. https://3v4l.org/ErDRY

Answer (score 0):

To use datetime objects in a loop like @ArleighHix's answer, I'd only modify the start date and use a calls of `min()` and `max()` in conjunction with `01` and `t` to ensure that date boundaries are not exceeded.

`max()` and `min()` are safe in this case because `Y-m-d` is a "big-endian" date format -- this means that the string can be evaluated as a simple string.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/FsLnX))

```
$start_date = new DateTime("2023-01-03");
$end_date = new DateTime("2023-12-15");

while ($start_date <= $end_date) {
    printf(
        "%s..%s\n",
        max($start_date->format("Y-m-01"), $start_date->format("Y-m-d")),
        min($end_date->format("Y-m-d"), $start_date->format("Y-m-t"))
    );
    $start_date->modify('+1 month first day of');
}
```

If your actual project requirement is to have non-full date ranges each month, then a refactored approach would be necessary.  Please provide a more challenging example by editing your question if this is a real concern/possibility.

Answer (score 0):

If your main goal is to output the start and end of each month within a given date range, inclusive of the end month, you can simplify this down to:

```php
$from = new DateTime("2023-01-01");
$to   = new DateTime("2023-12-31");

while ($from <= $to) {
    echo $from->format("Y-m-01") . ".." . $from->format("Y-m-t") . "\n";
    $from->add(new DateInterval("P1M"));
}
```

If you need to respect the `$from` and `$to` date, that is; if you need first date range to start at `$from` and the last date range to end at `$to`, you can adjust the above code slightly using the `max()` and `min()` functions:

```php
$from = new DateTime("2023-01-05");
$to   = new DateTime("2023-12-25");

$current = new DateTime($from->format("Y-m-01"));
while ($current <= $to) {
    echo max($from->format("Y-m-d"), $current->format("Y-m-01")) . ".." . min($to->format("Y-m-d"), $current->format("Y-m-t")) . "\n";
    $current->add(new DateInterval("P1M"));
}
```

Comment: Did my answer inspire you? It looks VERY similar.  Except your scripts don't respect the starting date when it is not the first day of the month: https://3v4l.org/qW3lt and https://3v4l.org/2ouT2  Would you feel ripped off if the shoe was on the other foot?

Comment: @mickmackusa not at all, I read the question made some comments and decided to create an answer as the comments didn't suffice. After looking at your answer (since your comment), you seem to work with the `strtotime` format which I've abandoned for a while due to some edge cases it doesn't play well with. My answer is purely class based (using DateInterval). No "ripping off" here, believe it or not such a simple question can result in many similar answers :)

Comment: There is `strtotime()` in my answer and there never has been any.  The only change yours makes is how you modify the date object.  Other than that it is the same or worse (for reasons that I've demonstrated in the first comment) than my answer.

Comment: @mickmackusa `modify("first day of")` and `modify("+1 month")` are using the `strtotime` format, or to be more technical, you use the "relative date format". You're answer does also account for a start date that is not the first of the month which mine doesn't, I shall make an edit now since it's been brought to attention, thanks!

Comment: Relative time expressions are no sin.  I'd even argue that they make the modification more obvious than the relatively cryptic expression of numbers and letters involved in `add()`ing a datetime interval.

Comment: @mickmackusa no one is saying they're a sin, I made the personal choice to abandon them in favour of class-based solutions which provide more benefits in the work I do. Nothing "cryptic" about a fully documented, easy to follow syntax for representing a date interval :)